# webstorm - filter results of search widget

Tags: webstorm

(using webstorm@11.0.1)

When I press double-SHIFT, this cool search widget opens.
The problem is that my project contains source code and minified production code, which causes my results to appear twice.

I'd like to tell the settings somewhere - show me results only from X Y Z (or - anything not from `dist` folder - just ignore it)

is it possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude that dist folder from the project – right-click on it in the project view, select Mark as - Excluded. As a result the files in that folder won't be indexed and won't appear in code completion results and any Go to... results.

Comment: That's sort of a solution, but now I can't see the code there, which is some disadvantage. Thanks anyway

Comment: The folder should be still visible in the project view and you can open its files in the editor with a double-click.